# call r script: Error in is_quosure(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, shiny

I'm getting this error when the app is initially run when loading before the user enters any data. The page loads then closes. The error message is in the RStudio console. I want it to call the function and show the message after the user clicks the Submit button. It looks like the error is on `}` above the `shinyApp(ui, server)`

```
Error in is_quosure(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

RShiny app.R file:

```
library(shiny)
library("stringr")
source("testLibrary.R")

# Define UI for dataset viewer app ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Churn"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ---- 
    sidebarPanel(
      
      textInput(inputId = "name",
                label = "Name:"),
      
      selectInput("gender", "Choose Gender:",
                  choices = c("Male", "Female"), selected = "Male"),
      
      numericInput("score", "Rating Score:", 10),
      
      actionButton("update", "Submit")
      
    ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("msg")
    )
    
  )
)

# Define server logic to summarize and view selected dataset ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  n <- eventReactive(input$name)
  g <- eventReactive(input$gender)
  s <- eventReactive(input$score)
  retval <- fxTest(n,g,s)
  
  output$msg <- renderText({
    retval
  })
  
}

# Create Shiny app ---- 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

testLibrary.R file:

```
library(RODBC, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(dplyr)
library("stringr")

fxTest <- function(n,g,s) {
  if(g == "Male")
  {
    cn = odbcConnect("MyODBC")
    ds <- sqlQuery(cn, "SELECT COUNT([Gender])
                        FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[BankCustomersChurn]
                        WHERE [Gender] = 'Male'
                        AND [Exited] = 1")
    
    ds2 = c("Hi ", n, ". The number of male customers that have left are ", ds, ". You rated this app ",s,".")
    ds3 <- paste(ds2, collapse = '') 
    
    odbcCloseAll()
    return(ds3)
  }
  if(g == "Female")
  {
    cn = odbcConnect("MyODBC")
    ds <- sqlQuery(cn, "SELECT COUNT([Gender])
                        FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[BankCustomersChurn]
                        WHERE [Gender] = 'Female'
                        AND [Exited] = 1")
    
    ds2 = c("Hi ", n, ". The number of female customers that have left are ", ds, ". You rated this app ",s,".")
    ds3 <- paste(ds2, collapse = '') 
    
    odbcCloseAll()
    return(ds3)
  }
  
}
```

Comment: `eventReactive` should be based on the `actionButton` i.e. `input$update`

Comment: According to documentation `Use observeEvent whenever you want to perform an action in response to an event. (Note that "recalculate a value" does not generally count as performing an action–see eventReactive for that.) The first argument is the event you want to respond to, and the second argument is a function that should be called whenever the event occurs.

Use eventReactive to create a calculated value that only updates in response to an event. ...`

Comment: I'm getting this error when the app is initially run when loading before the user enters any data. The page loads then closes. The error message is in the RStudio console. I want it to call the function and show the message after the user clicks the Submit button. How do you do that? Thank you.